# Notation for composition of functions of several variables

Tags: functions

The following is the standard notation for function composition of a single variable: $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$.

But is there common notation for the following: $f_1(f_2(x,y_1),y_2)$ when I have $N$ such functions? Here, $f_n: \mathbf{R}^3 \times \{1,2,3\} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^3 \times \{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: You could write the domain and range of the functions, that would help to understand your question.

Comment: To cover everything, you need some standard tools, such as projection from $\Bbb R^n$ (or whatever factors your combined domain has) to its single coordinates and combining functions. One might write something like $f_1\circ(f_2\circ (\pi_1\times \pi_2)\times \pi_3)$

Comment: @Lucas Thank you for the comment. I have edited my question accordingly.